# Meteor - Router.go() doesn't run when passed a variable

Tags: templates, meteor, static, path, iron-router

I have a template for a back button I've been reusing:

```
<template name="btnBack" label="" path="">
    <a href="" data-path="{{path}}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{label}}
    </a>
</template>
```

I pass it two fields, `label` and `path` statically.

My intention is to pass the static `path` field to `Iron-Router` to change the template rendered.

Setting `href` to `{{pathFor '{{path}}'}}`does not work. 
Neither does defining the attribute `onclick` as `Router.go('{{path}}')`.

In my third attempt, I passed the path to a data attribute: 
`data-path="{{path}}"`

And then I reference this attribute from within a template helper:

```
Template.btnBack.events({
  'click a': function(event, template) {
    var path = ''+event.target.dataset.path;
    console.log(path); 
    Router.go(path); 
  }
});
```

The `console.log` statement runs correctly, and outputs the statically-defined path in Google Chrome's console window.

`Router.go` however, does nothing - it doesn't even throw an error for an incorrect path in the console.

Here is how I instantiate the template: 
`{{> btnBack label="Back" path="home"}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add ```event.preventDefault()``` before ```var path=..```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Does event.preventDefault() need to be called to stop the link from trying to redirect to `href` (which is blank)?

Comment: if ```a``` has ```href``` attribute defined you need to call preventDefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try setting the link to

```
<template name="btnBack" label="" path="">
    <a href="{{ pathFor path }}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{label}}
    </a>
</template>
```

Comment: Your way worked, too. This is the less verbose one, so I think I'll go with it. Thanks!